# Turning 4 columns into 2

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with 4 columns and put it into pandas

```
username   likes  username2   likes2

Mill       2      Tim        10
John       3      Kim         2 
Tye        7      Rory        4
Clyde      8      Tann        9
Ellie      2      Ken         2
```

I am trying to:

1. Add username2 below username
2. Add likes2 below likes

Desired Output

```
username   likes 

Mill       2      
John       3      
Tye        7      
Clyde      8     
Ellie      2     
Tim        10
Kim        2 
Rory       4
Tann       9
Ken        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

- I know, there might be more concise way to do, this worked for me.

```
df1 = df['username'].append(df['username2']).reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df['likes'].append(df['likes2']).reset_index(drop=True)
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need top .melt()

```
 pd.melt(df, id_vars=['username'], value_vars=['likes', 'likes2'],value_name='likes').drop(columns=['variable'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A dirty one-liner:

```py
res = pd.concat([df[['username', 'likes']], df[['username2', 'likes2']].rename(columns={'username2': 'username', 'likes2': 'likes'})])
```

Answer (score 0):

A detailed way of Approach !!! Am not sure how many of you will like this.

```
first_df = df2.iloc[:,:2]
second_df = df2.iloc[:,2:]
a = []
for each in first_df.columns:
    a.append(each)
second_df.columns = a
Result = first_df.append(second_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way about it is [reshaping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the underlying numpy array and creating a new dataframe. Get the total number of entries in the dataframe, and divide by 2 (since you are aiming for only two columns) to get the number of rows in the final shape.

```
res = (pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.to_numpy(),(df.size//2,2))
       ,columns=['username','likes'])
       )

    username    likes
0       Mill    2
1       Tim     10
2       John    3
3       Kim     2
4       Tye     7
5       Rory    4
6       Clyde   8
7       Tann    9
8       Ellie   2
9       Ken     2
```

### Update

The data has a defined pattern (some columns start with `username`, others start with `like`). As such, you can use the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html)

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
df.pivot_longer(names_to=("username", "likes"), 
                names_pattern=("^username", "likes"))

username    likes
0   Mill    2
1   John    3
2   Tye     7
3   Clyde   8
4   Ellie   2
5   Tim     10
6   Kim     2
7   Rory    4
8   Tann    9
9   Ken     2
```